# Cannot pass result from wordpress's plugins_url to str_replace. Get error:

Tags: php, wordpress

I am placing the result of the function `plugins_url` into a variable and passig that to `str_replace` but that throws the error:

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference
```

My code:

```
$baseURL = plugins_url( "somefile.php", dirname(__FILE__) );

//This throws an error
$baseURL = str_replace( "something", "anotherthing", $baseURL, 1 );
```

How do I alter the response from that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last argument has to be in a variable

```
$count = 1;
$baseURL = str_replace( "something", "anotherthing", $baseURL, $count );
```

Comment: Thank you! I will mark it as the answer when it allows me in 9 minutes.

Comment: @DonRhummy Cool, thanks.  This is a weird error that actually comes up in other places as well, apparently due to an existing memory issue (the specifics of which are hard to track down), so while it'd be great to know *why* we have to, I suppose it'll have to be enough to know *what* to do.